# Unfamiliar Java Syntax

Tags: java, syntax

I am working through an [AWS tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/java-flow-making-changes-example-scenario.html) and came across Java syntax that I don't quite understand.

```
protected AmazonSimpleWorkflow service = AmazonSimpleWorkflowClientBuilder.defaultClient();
{
    try {
        AmazonSimpleWorkflowClientBuilder.defaultClient().registerDomain(new RegisterDomainRequest().withName(domain).withDescription("desc").withWorkflowExecutionRetentionPeriodInDays("7"));
    } catch (DomainAlreadyExistsException e) {
    }
}
```

I thought that try / catch blocks needed to be inside of a function, but this example is using it directly after an assignment. What exactly is the operation going on here and what is the name of it?